# Json parser, incorrectly parsing string as a number

Tags: json, haskell, parsec

I'm still pretty new to Haskell and functional programming in general, so I'm writing a small program with Parsec to parse JSON and pretty print it as a means of learning basic concepts. This is what I have so far:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

data JValue = JString String
            | JNumber Double
            | JBool Bool
            | JNull
            | JObject [(String, JValue)]
            | JArray [JValue]
              deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

parseJString, parseJNumber, parseJBool, parseJNull :: Parser JValue
parseJString = do
    str <- between (char '"') (char '"') (many (noneOf "\""))
    return . JString $ str

parseJNumber = do
    num <- many digit
    return . JNumber . read $ num

parseJBool = do
    val <- string "true" <|> string "false"
    case val of
        "true"  -> return (JBool True)
        "false" -> return (JBool False)

parseJNull = string "null" >> return JNull

parseJValue :: Parser JValue
parseJValue =   parseJString 
            <|> parseJNumber 
            <|> parseJBool 
            <|> parseJNull
```

For now, I'm assuming that the numbers are integers. Individually, `parseJString`, `parseJNumber`, `parseJBool`, and `parseJNull` work as expected in ghci. Additionally, `parseJValue` correctly parses strings and numbers.

```
ghci> parse parseJString "test" "\"test input\""
Right (JString "test input")
ghci> parse parseJNumber "test" "345"
Right (JNumber 345.0)
ghci> parse parseJBool "test" "true"
Right (JBool True)
ghci> parse parseJNull "test" "null"
Right JNull
ghci> parse parseJValue "test" "\"jvalue test\""
Right (JString "jvalue test")
ghci> parse parseJValue "test" "789"
Right (JNumber 789.0)
```

`parseJValue` fails, however, when I try to parse `true`, `false`, or `null`, and I get an interesting error.

```
ghci> parse parseJValue "test" "true"
Right (JNumber *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I get a successful parse, but the parse returns a `JNumber` followed by an error stating that Prelude.read failed. I feel like I'm missing some core concept in building my parsers, but I can't see where I've gone wrong. Also, am I making any beginner mistakes with my code, i.e. would any of this be considered "bad" haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `many` in `parseJNumber`. It is also a valid parse, when no character of the following string is consumed ("many p applies the parser p zero or more times. [...]"). What you need is `many1`:

```
parseJNumber = do
  num <- many1 (oneOf "0123456789")
  return $ JNumber (read num :: Double)
```

Edit:

Somehow, I think your combination of `(.)` and `($)` looks kind of weird. I use (.) when I can get rid of a function parameter (like in the usage of `(>>=)`) and ($) when I'm to lazy to write parentheses. In your function `parseJString` you do not need `(.)` in order to get the right binding precedences. (I did the same transformation in the code above.)

```
parseJString = do
  str <- between (char '"') (char '"') (many (noneOf "\""))
  return $ JString str
```

Additionally, you could eliminate code-repetition by refactoring `parseJBool`:

```
parseJBool = do
  val <- string "true" <|> string "false"
  return (case val of
    "true"  -> JBool True
    "false" -> JBool False)
```

I would even rewrite the case-construct into a (total) local function:

```
parseJBool = (string "true" <|> string "false") >>= return . toJBool
 where
  -- there are only two possible strings to pattern match
  toJBool "true" = JBool True
  toJBool _      = JBool False
```

Last but not least, you can easily transform your other functions to use `(>>=)` instead of do-blocks.

```
-- additionally, you do not need an extra type signature for `read`
-- the constructor `JNumber` already infers the correct type
parseJNumber =
  many1 (oneOf "0123456789") >>= return . JNumber . read

parseJString =
  between (char '"') (char '"') (many (noneOf "\"")) >>= return . JString
```

Comment: I definitely agree with the refactoring changes you suggested, however Syntastic in vim gives me a rather vague warning to instead use `liftM` whenever I use `>>= return`. Is there a reason to change that, or should that be ignored?

Comment: You should probably use `liftM f x` which is exactly equivalent to `x >>= return . f`. Or even better, you could use `fmap f x` (which works as long as you have a `Functor` instance) or `f <$> x` (which works as long as you have an `Applicative` instance).

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `many1 digit` rather than `many digit`. A `many` succeeds on zero occurrences of the argument.

Compare:

```
ghci> parse (many digit) "test" "true"
Right ""
ghci> parse (many1 digit) "test" "true"
unexpected "t"
expecting digit
```

So in your case, `parseJNumber` within `parseJValue` will succeed and return an empty string which is then passed to `read`. But `read "" :: Double` fails.